# Log RestServiceBase request and response

Tags: logging, servicestack

I'm using an old project that still references `RestServiceBase<TRequest>` and I know need to log all calls request and response for this API.

I can easily **go through each service implementation** and add something like:

```
// get reponse from request
object response = this.OnGetSpecificAccount(request);

// log
Logs.LogRequestWithResponse(
                this.RequestContext, this.Request.HttpMethod, response.ToJson());
```

and after some extraction and inserting into the database I  would get a log looking like:

[image]

> [see larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYpWW.png)

But I was wondering if there's already some **Logging implementation** that I could take advantage and can easily hook up to the base class and log this automatically, as I would want to log the `Auth` call as well (in order to get the `username` that is being authenticated and match the `username` with the `session`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is built in logging using the `RequestLogsFeature`, this is aimed at debugging your project.

However ServiceStack does make it easy to get at all the relevant information you need by using a request filter that will be run for each request.

The code below demonstrates how you would record how long a request takes, and the other values you were looking for, such as SessionId, IP address, Verb, URI, etc.

```cs
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    // Record the time the request started.
    this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) => req.SetItem("StartTime", DateTime.Now));

    // The request has been processed, ready to send response
    this.GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, responseDto) => {

        var startTime = req.GetItem("StartTime") as DateTime?;
        var endTime = DateTime.Now;

        var log = new {

            // Request URL
            Url = req.AbsoluteUri,

            // Verb
            Verb = req.Verb,

            // Session Id
            SessionId = req.GetSessionId(),

            // IP Address
            Ip = req.RemoteIp,

            // Record the Request DTO
            Request = req.Dto.ToJson(),

            // Record the Response DTO
            Response = responseDto.ToJson(),

            // Get the start time that was recorded when the request started
            StartTime = startTime.Value,

            // Time request finished
            EndTime = endTime,

            // Determine the duration of the request
            Duration = endTime - startTime.Value,

        };

        // Save the log to the database
        // Resolve the database connection
        var db = TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection();
        // ...

    });
}
```

[image: Log screenshot]

I hope this helps.

Comment: It helped a lot, though as I stated in the first line, I'm not using the lastest version and for such I have no `GlobalResponseFilters`/`GlobalRequestFilters` but I got similar... though, in my version I have no access to `req.Dto` as it's not part of the properties of the `req` object, but I'm hoping that `req.InputStream` will have something if it's not a `GET`. All in all, thanks a million!

Comment: It does support response logging, please see the IrequestLogger interface, https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/IRequestLogger.cs . We created a databaseRequestLogger to persist to db and chose not to save responses so as not to bloat the database.

Comment: @BrandonG Thanks. I stand corrected on that front, I have removed that line. I like implementing the logging through the request filters as it provides fine grain control of the log-able values, such as specific headers etc. I'd appreciate your answer if you provided an implementation.

Comment: @balexandre Sorry I never picked up on the v3 requirement, but as you note these same filters are available in v3 but under a different name. As for the lack of `req.Dto`, you could save the `requestDto` from the request filter as a `ToJson()` string in the request `Items` collections, and carry that over to the response filter. All the best with your project :)

Comment: darn, why didn't I thought about that! Good idea, once again, thanks a million!

Comment: @Scott I added our implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can log all the request/responses using the [RequestLogsFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger). At my company a co-worker implemented the ability to save this information to a database. We however don't log the responses.

**Update** Someone asked for our implementation. We originally used NewtonSoft.Json for json but I could never see the request data in the UI as it was deserialized. So I switched to Servicestack json and it worked as expected. Here it is:

**DatabaseLoggingFeature.cs**

```
   public class DatabaseLoggingFeature : IPlugin
{
    public DatabaseLoggingFeature(string connectionStringKey, int? capacity = null)
    {
        AtRestPath = "/requestlogs";
        ConnectionStringKey = connectionStringKey;
        Capacity = capacity;
        RequiredRoles = new[] {RoleNames.Admin};
        EnableErrorTracking = true;
        EnableRequestBodyTracking = false;
        ExcludeRequestDtoTypes = new[] {typeof (RequestLogs), typeof (ResourceRequest), typeof (Resources)};
        HideRequestBodyForRequestDtoTypes = new[]
        {
            typeof (Auth), typeof (Registration)
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets connection string
    /// </summary>
    public string ConnectionStringKey { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     RequestLogs service Route, default is /requestlogs
    /// </summary>
    public string AtRestPath { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Turn On/Off Session Tracking
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnableSessionTracking { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Turn On/Off Logging of Raw Request Body, default is Off
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnableRequestBodyTracking { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Turn On/Off Tracking of Responses
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnableResponseTracking { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Turn On/Off Tracking of Exceptions
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnableErrorTracking { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Size of InMemoryRollingRequestLogger circular buffer
    /// </summary>
    public int? Capacity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Limit access to /requestlogs service to these roles
    /// </summary>
    public string[] RequiredRoles { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Change the RequestLogger provider. Default is InMemoryRollingRequestLogger
    /// </summary>
    public IRequestLogger RequestLogger { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Don't log requests of these types. By default RequestLog's are excluded
    /// </summary>
    public Type[] ExcludeRequestDtoTypes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Don't log request body's for services with sensitive information.
    ///     By default Auth and Registration requests are hidden.
    /// </summary>
    public Type[] HideRequestBodyForRequestDtoTypes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Registers plugin with service stack
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appHost">Application Host configuration object.</param>
    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.RegisterService<RequestLogsService>(AtRestPath);

        IRequestLogger requestLogger = RequestLogger ?? new DatabaseRequestLogger(ConnectionStringKey);
        requestLogger.EnableSessionTracking = EnableSessionTracking;
        requestLogger.EnableResponseTracking = EnableResponseTracking;
        requestLogger.EnableRequestBodyTracking = EnableRequestBodyTracking;
        requestLogger.EnableErrorTracking = EnableErrorTracking;
        requestLogger.RequiredRoles = RequiredRoles;
        requestLogger.ExcludeRequestDtoTypes = ExcludeRequestDtoTypes;
        requestLogger.HideRequestBodyForRequestDtoTypes = HideRequestBodyForRequestDtoTypes;

        appHost.Register(requestLogger);

        if (EnableRequestBodyTracking)
        {
            appHost.PreRequestFilters.Insert(0,
                (httpReq, httpRes) => { httpReq.UseBufferedStream = EnableRequestBodyTracking; });
        }
    }
}
```

**DatabaseRequestLogger.cs**

```
public class DatabaseRequestLogger : IRequestLogger
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Instance of the current database connection;
    /// </summary>
    private readonly DbConnection _connection;

    public DatabaseRequestLogger(string connectionStringKey)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionStringKey))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("connectionStringKey");
        }

        if (_connection != null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionStringKey)) return;
        ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connectionStrings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;

        if (connectionStrings == null) return;
        foreach (ConnectionStringSettings setting in connectionStrings.Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>()
            .Where(setting => setting.Name == connectionStringKey))
        {
            ConnectionString = setting.ConnectionString;
            ProviderName = setting.ProviderName;
            _connection = GetConnection(ProviderName, ConnectionString);
        }
    }

    public ILog log { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets connection string
    /// </summary>
    public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets provider name
    /// </summary>
    public string ProviderName { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnableErrorTracking { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnableRequestBodyTracking { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnableResponseTracking { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnableSessionTracking { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public Type[] ExcludeRequestDtoTypes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns latest log entries.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="take">number of records to retrieve.</param>
    /// <returns>List of RequestLogEntry</returns>
    public List<RequestLogEntry> GetLatestLogs(int? take)
    {
        var entries = new List<RequestLogEntry>();

        if (_connection != null)
        {
            if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                _connection.Open();
            }

            using (DbCommand cmd = _connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                string query = "SELECT {0} FROM [dbo].[RequestLog] ORDER BY LoggedDate DESC";

                query = take.HasValue
                    ? string.Format(query, "TOP " + take.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " * ")
                    : string.Format(query, "*");

                cmd.Connection = _connection;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = query;

                try
                {
                    DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        var serializer = new JsonSerializer<RequestLogEntry>();

                        RequestLogEntry entry = serializer.DeserializeFromString(dr["LogEntry"].ToString());

                        entries.Add(entry);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                    if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        cmd.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return entries;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public Type[] HideRequestBodyForRequestDtoTypes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public string[] RequiredRoles { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Logs request/response data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requestDto"></param>
    /// <param name="response">instance of <see cref="IHttpResponse" /> object.</param>
    /// <param name="requestContext"></param>
    /// <param name="duration"></param>
    public void Log(IRequestContext requestContext, object requestDto, object response, TimeSpan duration)
    {
        Type requestType = requestDto != null ? requestDto.GetType() : null;

        // if we don't want to track the request simply bail out.
        if (ExcludeRequestDtoTypes != null
            && requestType != null
            && ExcludeRequestDtoTypes.Contains(requestType))
        {
            return;
        }

        //Move this code to another class and create an interface

        if (_connection != null)
        {
            if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                _connection.Open();
            }

            using (DbCommand cmd = _connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = _connection;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "spLogRequest";

                var entry = new RequestLogEntry
                {
                    DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    RequestDuration = duration
                };

                IHttpRequest httpRequest = requestContext != null ? requestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>() : null;

                if (httpRequest != null)
                {
                    entry.HttpMethod = httpRequest.HttpMethod;
                    entry.AbsoluteUri = httpRequest.AbsoluteUri;
                    entry.PathInfo = httpRequest.PathInfo;
                    entry.IpAddress = requestContext.IpAddress;
                    entry.Headers = httpRequest.Headers.ToDictionary();
                    entry.Referer = httpRequest.Headers[HttpHeaders.Referer];
                    entry.ForwardedFor = httpRequest.Headers[HttpHeaders.XForwardedFor];
                    entry.RequestDto = requestDto;
                    entry.Items = httpRequest.Items;
                    entry.UserAuthId = httpRequest.GetItemOrCookie(HttpHeaders.XUserAuthId);
                    entry.SessionId = httpRequest.GetSessionId();
                    entry.Session = EnableSessionTracking ? httpRequest.GetSession() : null;

                    if (HideRequestBodyForRequestDtoTypes != null
                        && requestType != null
                        && !HideRequestBodyForRequestDtoTypes.Contains(requestType))
                    {
                        entry.RequestDto = requestDto;

                        entry.FormData = httpRequest.FormData.ToDictionary();

                        if (EnableRequestBodyTracking)
                        {
                            entry.RequestBody = httpRequest.GetRawBody();
                        }
                    }

                    if (!response.IsErrorResponse())
                    {
                        if (EnableResponseTracking)
                        {
                            entry.ResponseDto = response;
                        }
                    }
                }

                DbParameter requestParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
                requestParam.ParameterName = "@LogEntry";
                requestParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                requestParam.DbType = DbType.String;
                //JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo = true;
                requestParam.Value = new JsonSerializer<RequestLogEntry>().SerializeToString(entry);

                DbParameter requestDurationParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
                requestDurationParam.ParameterName = "@RequestDuration";
                requestDurationParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                requestDurationParam.DbType = DbType.Int64;
                requestDurationParam.Value = entry.RequestDuration.Ticks;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(requestParam);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(requestDurationParam);

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error("Error occurred saving request log entry to the database in Log.", ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                    if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        cmd.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```